# How to turn a set points into a GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, graphics, drawing

The question is more likely not about programming, but about algorithms. I think so, at least.

So, I have a set of parallel lines with step = 1 pixel. I can turn them into a set of points on a plane by iterating throught each line from one end to the other. I will get something like an example (look at the picture). The lines and pixels that belong to them, that is, the shape itself, are displayed here.

I work in WinForms .net 3.5, all this will be drawn directly on the form via `Graphics g.Draw()`

Question: is it possible to turn this set of points into some kind of `GraphicsPath` or `Polygon`? Drawing one such object will take much less time than hundreds of parallel lines. I'm not talking about every pixel at all.

The shape of the figure can be any, including as in the picture. What's more important - the shape (lines) can be rotated 45 degrees counterclockwise.

[image: Example]

Comment: You can try this: Add the lines to a GraphicsPath and then look at its PathPoints. - Or add the left Points to a list and the the right ones to a 2nd list. Then reverse the 2nd list, combine them and create a path from them by doing a path.AddLines - You will need to do special cases for  the concave porions like the upper right set of lines, though

Comment: @TaW: You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I don't write answers here any longer.

Comment: How fast does the conversion have to be? Is this a situation where the set of lines is known ahead of time and you're drawing them repeatedly?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, if you mean how fast points should convert to polygon... I think about 5 seconds maximum. I'm ready to wait a little for convertation but save time when redrawing form

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the figure is simply connected. Depending on how your graphics system works (I'm not familiar), this assumption might not be needed.

The idea is to turn each line into pixels and each pixel into its four counterclockwise oriented boundaries. For example, a shape like

```
 _____
|_____|
  |__|
```

becomes

```
|<--|<--|<--|<--|<--
|  ^|  ^|  ^|  ^|  ^
v  |v  |v  |v  |v  |
-->|-->|-->|-->|-->|
       |<--|<--
       |  ^|  ^
       v  |v  |
       -->|-->|
```

. Everywhere there are two opposing boundaries, delete them.

```
|<-- <-- <-- <-- <--
|                  ^
v                  |
--> -->         -->|
       |       
       |      ^
       v      |
       --> -->|
```

Then compute the circular list of boundaries in order and group them into lines. This is easy when there's only one entry and one exit to each grid point.

For diagonally adjacent pixels, this gets a little more complicated, e.g.,

```
 _
|_|_
  |_|
```

turns into

```
|<--
|  ^
v  a
-A>|
    |<B-
    b  ^
    v  |
    -->|
```

and then you have a choice. The right choice is whichever arc emerges next in clockwise order from the entry arc, which pairs A with a and B with b.